# How to make a web site on CD searchable

Tags: javascript, html, cd-rom

I have a client who has a static site with several HTML indexes of MS Word and .xls files they wish to distribute on CD Rom (i.e., no web server). They would like to make this content searchable (both the HTML and the linked DOC and XLS files). I'm tempted to just make a PDF out of this whole thing, but it seems like a blunt tool.

Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use javascript to perform such searches!

Look at this: http://www.atrise.com/everyfind/

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Zoom Website Search Engine](http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/index.html) - they have a CD Search option.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not include a copy of the [Cassini web server](http://www.ultidev.com/products/index.htm) and preindex the data into a SQLite database?

Comment: Installing an app on the client is overkill. This is for end users.

Comment: Cassini doesn't require an install on the client.  It is designed for running off a CD!